# JavaFX - set programmatically the destination path to print directly a node to pdf file

Tags: pdf, javafx, printing

I want to print a node to a pdf file using "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer. Supposing that the Printer object is already extracted I have the next function which is working perfectly.

```
public static void printToPDF(Printer printer, Node node) {

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
    if (job != null) {
        job.getJobSettings().setPrintQuality(PrintQuality.HIGH);

        PageLayout pageLayout = job.getPrinter().createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT,
                Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);

        boolean printed = job.printPage(pageLayout, node);
        if (printed) {
            job.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing failed.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }
}
```

The only issue that I have here, is that a dialog box is popping up and asking for a destination path to save the pdf. I was struggling to find a solution to set the path programmatically, but with no success. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research I came with an ugly hack. I accessed jobImpl private field from PrinterJob, and I took attributes out of it. Therefore I inserted the destination attribute, and apparently it is working as requested. I know it is not nice, but ... is kind of workable. If you have any nicer suggestion, please do not hesitate to post them.

```
         try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field field = job.getClass().getDeclaredField("jobImpl");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            PrinterJobImpl jobImpl = (PrinterJobImpl) field.get(job);
            field.setAccessible(false);

            field = jobImpl.getClass().getDeclaredField("printReqAttrSet");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            PrintRequestAttributeSet printReqAttrSet = (PrintRequestAttributeSet) field.get(jobImpl);
            field.setAccessible(false);

            printReqAttrSet.add(new Destination(new java.net.URI("file:/C:/deleteMe/wtv.pdf")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```