# Saving pdf format via FileChooser prompts a second dialog box in java

Tags: java

I set a save dialog box which enables me to save the file as PDF and PNG format. Saving as PNG does not have any problem but saving as PDF will prompt another save dialog box before saving the pdf file. Below is my code:

```
fc.setFilter(new ExtensionFilter("PDF Files", "*.pdf"), new extensionFilter("PNG Files", "*.png"));
File file = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
String fileName = file.getCanonicalPath();
PdfPrinter printer = new PdfPrinter();

if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) {            
            printer.PrintPDF(canvasForPrint, fileName);         
        } else {
           //save as PNG
        }
```

Then the PrintPDF() method:

```
public void PrintPDF(Node node, String name) throws PdfPrintException {
Printer thePdfPrinter = null;

if (printer.getName().equals("Microsoft Print to PDF")) {
    thePdfPrinter = printer;
    }

PrinterJob job = null;
job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(thePdfPrinter);
try {
    job.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(layout);
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        job.getJobSettings().setJobName("PlaneXYChart");
    } else {
        job.getJobSettings().setJobName(name);
    }
} finally {
        if (job != null) {
            job.endJob();
}
```

Codes are minimized for the sake of brevity. I don't understand why the parameters are not working and it's again asking the second time to save the pdf file. If somebody has the same issue, kindly share your solutions.

Update: During debugging, the second dialog pops up in the line `if (job != null) {`.

Comment: @Amessihel The second dialog box is basically the same as the first one. Only the second has the PDF only as a **Save as type** while the first one has PDF and PNG, as being set via `fc.setFilter `.

Comment: @Amessihel I updated my post. Sorry for the messy code samples. The second dialog pops up in the `if (job != null) {` line.

Answer (score 0):

After a search, I came to the conclusion there is not a generic way to perform that. It seems to be printer specific.

The ugly way somebody posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684422) would work for your virtual printer ("Microsoft Print to PDF"). He's using java reflection to achieve it, which seems to be, as he said, "not nice but workable".

This [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/103855/545165) question lists some free ([free as in free speech *and* as in free beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre)) virtual printers. Using them with JavaFX could lead you to resolve your issue.

(If you want to purchase a very good solution for programmatically PDF production, however it's closed-source, you can have a look to [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com), but breath before looking at the pricing. :-))

Comment: Thank you for your time. I was hoping to have a solution that could work something like the Microsoft Word which you can just `Save as type` your work **directly** into a bunch of format types (but open source).